# Apex form condition

Tags: forms, apex

Can we have a condition clause in APEX form :
   Value of Item / Column in Expression 1 = Expression 2,
    where expression1 is a form variable like P19__ROW_last_update_ts and 
    the second expression2 is a sql query like select max(date_max) from table

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a property on your form controller that executes the query and returns the result. The property will look something like:

```
public String getExampleProperty {
   get {
     return [/*some query in here*/].someProperty;
   }
}
```

And then in your form, you'll reference the value like:

```
{!exampleProperty}
```

Note that you don't use the 'get' prefix in your visual force markup.

Hope this helps!